# MPI::Boost compilation problems

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-code, mpi, centos7

i'm not able to compile my mpi::bost program in C++. My system is: Centos 7 and I'm using VS Code. Includes are not the problem, the compiler seems to read them correctly. But when I try to call members of the boost libraries like mpi::environment the compiler says:
undefined reference to `boost::mpi::environment::environment(bool)'

While I installed the boost libaries, I followed this tutorial:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html

I'm only not sure if i managed to link the libraries correctly (last step) In my opinion "-I/home/ljacob/usr/include" as a flag to the compiler should do the job...

```
//my header//paths are all 100% correct

    ....
    #include "mpi.h"
    ....
    //and the boost libraries
    #include <boost/mpi.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp> 
    #include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp> 
    namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    //this works
        MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
        int my_rank;
        int processes;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &processes);
     //and this doesn't
        mpi::environment env;
        mpi::communicator world; 
    }


  //My c_cpp_properties.json looks like this:

    {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Linux",
                "includePath": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/x86_64-redhat-linux",
                    "/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/32",
                    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/include",
                    "/home/ljacob/usr/include", //here are the boost includes
                    "/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/tr1",
                    "/usr/include/linux",
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/lib/gcc",
                    "/usr/lib64/mpich/lib",
                    "/usr/lib64",
                    "/usr/local/bin",
                    "/usr/local/lib",
                    "/home/ljacob/usr/lib"//here are the boost libraries
                ],
                "defines": [],
                "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/mpic++",
                "cStandard": "c11",
                "cppStandard": "c++17",
                "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
            },
            {
                "name": "Linux_config_build",
                "includePath": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
                ],enter code here
                "defines": [],
                "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/mpic++",
                "cStandard": "c11",
                "cppStandard": "c++17",
                "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
            }
        ],
        "version": 4
    }

//and this is my tasks.json

{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {

            "type": "shell",
            "label": "mpic++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/local/bin/mpic++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-I/home/ljacob/usr/include",
                "${file}",
                "-fopenmp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/local/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The compiler runs with:

```
> Executing task in folder Workspace_MPI_OpenMP: /usr/local/bin/mpic++ -g -L/home/ljacob/usr/include/boost -L/home/ljacob/usr/lib -I/home/ljacob/usr/include /DATA/JACOB/Codes/Workspace_MPI_OpenMP/Flowanalysis_2019_v1.0.cpp -fopenmp -o /DATA/JACOB/Codes/Workspace_MPI_OpenMP/Flowanalysis_2019_v1.0 <
```

The error massage it creates is:

```
/tmp/ccYFKRpP.o: In function `main':
/DATA/JACOB/Codes/Workspace_MPI_OpenMP/Flowanalysis_2019_v1.0.cpp:92: undefined reference to `boost::mpi::environment::environment(bool)'
/DATA/JACOB/Codes/Workspace_MPI_OpenMP/Flowanalysis_2019_v1.0.cpp:93: undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::communicator()'
/DATA/JACOB/Codes/Workspace_MPI_OpenMP/Flowanalysis_2019_v1.0.cpp:92: undefined reference to `boost::mpi::environment::~environment()'
/DATA/JACOB/Codes/Workspace_MPI_OpenMP/Flowanalysis_2019_v1.0.cpp:92: undefined reference to `boost::mpi::environment::~environment()'
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

For some reason the compiler doesn't understand that it already has the right libraries. And I don't have any clue why. When i ctrk+leftclick on the mpi::environment initialization, it directly links to the right file...(environment.hpp) Which means that the declaration should be correct. But why does the compiler itself doesn't get what to do? 
Thank you for your answers

Comment: `-I...` is a path to the include files, and this is used at compile time. You seem to have a link issue (beter copy/paste the error message), and that generally requires `-L...` with the path to the boost.MPI libraries.

Comment: please edit your question with the error message, it is virtually impossible to read as a comment. Also please extract the link command from your UI. You also need to add the boost mpi library with the `-l` flag. In my box, that would be `mpicxx -L/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -lboost_mpi-mt ...`

Comment: Hello Gilles, thanks again. In my boost library folder /usr/ljacob/include/lib are only libboost_system.a and some .so files. I don't see any lboost_mpi-mt file. Sorry, it might be a stupid question but which library do I have to add? When I link the entire folder with -L to the compiler, it still gives the same error...

Comment: Is there a libboost_mpi.so?

Comment: Yes, there are 4 of them:
/usr/include/lib/libboost_mpi.so
/usr/include/lib/libboost_mpi.so.1
/usr/include/lib/libboost_mpi.so.1.70
/usr/include/lib/libboost_mpi.so.1.70.0

When I link them with "-L/home/ljacob/usr/lib -libboost_mpi.so" it terminates with the same exit code like before. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Where are your libraries ? You already mentioned three different paths (!)

Comment: The boost libraries are in /usr/include/lib/. Which I already included with -L. You mentioned a "-l" command. How do I apply that to the library? I tried -l/home/ljacob/usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so but that does'nt work...

Comment: `-L/usr/include/lib -lboost_mpi`

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry to steal your time but it still doesn't fix the problem. Do you mean the libboost_mpi library? Because that is the only lib which is in that folder. There is no -lboost_mpi for me. For whatever reason. Sorry again to steal your time... :-( I really appreciate your help!

Comment: These flags will automagically *translate* into `/use/include/lib/libboost_mpi.so`

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568713/unable-to-compile-simple-boost-mpi-example try to compile this from the command line first.

Comment: Okay, I will do that and tell, if it works or not. Maybe it's the same issue... Cheers

Comment: I tried to adjust the compiler settings with the instructions in the other thread. Even if I'm 100% in the right folder where the libraries are, the -lboost_mpi gives the same error massage as before. When I add only -lboost_mpi, the compiler chrashes with:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_mpi

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to tell you that I've fixed it! The issue was a combination of:
1. The libraries were installed twice without removing the previous installation -crashed the links between the libraries for some reason
2. I had to link the -lboost_serialization as well to the compiler
Thank you again Gilles for your help! You pointed me to the right direction.
Cheers